# Is there a faster way to access I/O register with inp() and outp()?

Tags: c, io, dos, intel, cpu-registers

My application is running under DOS on a computer with an Intel Atom Z520PT processor running at 1.333GHz and a clock pulse of about 0.75ns. I use the C compiler in VisualStudio 2010.

I use many inp() and outp() commands to access the procesor's I/O registers.
Each of these commands takes around 2.2µs. Getting an application-specific data array from the I/O device requires 40 to 50 outp() and inp() calls, so I can only do this 10 times per ms.

Is there any way to access I/O registers faster? Why are these commands taking so much time? Could I make this faster by using asm instead of C?

Comment: Are you actually running DOS (as in an actual real-mode DOS OS, which is pretty rare these days) or are you running a DOS program in a Windows console window where the I/O instructions are being virtualized?  Or something else altogether? I don't think the C compiler in VS 2010 will generate DOS executables.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I second the question! - MSVC 2010 can't create 16 bit applications. My answer assumed the OP means real 16-bit DOS, for example an embedded application on a PC-104 or similar.

Answer (score 4):

**It is unlikely that you can access these registers any faster.** You didn't state what the device is, but accessing *any* register off the archaic x86 I/O or ISA bus device is going to be very slow. Rule of thumb is on the order of 1µs access times. So your numbers are about right.

**I/O to the legacy x86 I/O bus is intrinsically slow.** To speed it up is a hardware problem (different bus, different interface, etc.), not a software one.

EDIT: <s>You didn't state the compiler you are using,</s> *MSVC 2010 can't compile for DOS,* but it is pretty safe to assume that any of the 16-bit compilers *that can* will be similar. For example, in [Open Watcom](https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2/blob/d4f14b7f5576fb541853cce8832d4001cd940c48/bld/clib/intel/c/outp.c), `outp()` and `inp()` are just function wrappers around the assembler primitive anyhow. The function call overhead is around 1-2 clocks, so is negligible compared to the thousands of cycles the inp() or outp() is going to take. **So Inline Assembler isn't going to help at all.**

Depending on the hardware, the only chance of better speed is *if* there is some other method of access, for example PCI bus-master DMA.

Comment: Or if not DMA, then memory-mapped I/O might be faster, right?  So you can use write-combining `movnt` stores where it's safe, and even potentially movnt loads.

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree, the key thing would be that it is not an I/O "port" access or the 8 bit IO bus - basically anything else would be faster.

Comment: I don't have much of an idea of the relative performance difference of `inb` / `inl` / `outb` / ... vs. MMIO, so I had to ask.  I wasn't sure if `in` was inherently slower than a read from MMIO, or what, but I assume so.  Mostly I just tune user-space unprivileged stuff.